# Interlinked classes

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I have 2 classes: A and B.
 
I want:
- class A to have a pointer to B
- methods of class B to have access to private members of A

When trying to compile I'm getting a list of dozen of strange errors like this:

> "error C2614: 'A' : illegal member initialization: 'b_ptr' is not a base or member."

How to eliminate them?

Overall situation: 
Class A - it's a big entity, Class B - it's an auxiliary class which reading input text files and tunes settings of Class A respectively. Maybe something wrong with this OOD?

**"A.h":**

```
#include "B.h"
class A
{
    // friend class B;
public:
    A() : b_ptr(new B(this)){};
private:
    int a_1;
    int a_2;
private:
    B* b_ptr;
};
```

**"B.h":**

```
#include "A.h"
class B
{
public:
    B(A*const a) : a_ptr(a) {};
private:
    A* const a_ptr;
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a cyclic dependency of header files without include guards.

**One possible solution**

Your "B.h" just needs a forward declaration. Change to:

```
class A;

class B
{
public:
    B(A*const a) : a_ptr(a) {};
private:
    A* const a_ptr;
};
```